# Python - run part of code multipel times at once

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
configurationsFile = "file.csv"
configurations = []


def loadConfigurations():
    with open(configurationsFile) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        line_count = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            url = row[0]
            line_count += 1
            configurations.append({"url": url})
        print(f'{line_count} urls loaded.')

loadConfigurations()


failedConfigs = []

session_requests = requests.session()

for config in configurations:
    try:
        "Do something with the url loaded fron file.csv"

            
    except Exception  as e: 
        print(e)
        failedConfigs.append(config)

if len(failedConfigs) > 0:
    print("These errored out:")
    for theConfig in failedConfigs:
        print("ERROR: {}".format(theConfig['url']))
```

It reads urls from a csv file, and then runs a code for each of the urls that's listed in the csv file.
The only "problem" is if the csv file contains a lot of urls, then it takes a long time to run thru them all. So I'm looking for a way to run more then one url at a time.

I'm not that good with python so I don't even know if it's possible.
But the question is, is there some way to tell the code to run, say 5 urls at once instead of just 1?

Comment: Maybe take a look at multi-threaded programs https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: You can also use asyncio. But you should convert your main function into a coroutine. Then you can use asyncio.gather()
And you can use multiprocessing but I don't know much about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) class. Here is an example:

```
from threading import Thread

def read(file, start, end):
    with open(file, 'r') as r:
        for i, v in enumerate(r):
            if start <= i < end:
                print(v)

file = "file.txt"

t1 = Thread(target=read, args=(file, 0, 100))
t2 = Thread(target=read, args=(file, 100, 200))
t3 = Thread(target=read, args=(file, 200, 300))
t4 = Thread(target=read, args=(file, 300, 400))
t5 = Thread(target=read, args=(file, 400, 500))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t3.start()
t5.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()
t5.join()
```

Or use a loop:

```
from threading import Thread

def read(file, start, end):
    with open(file, 'r') as r:
        for i, v in enumerate(r):
            if start <= i < end:
                print(v)

file = "file.txt"

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    threads.append(Thread(target=read, args=(file, i * 100, (i + 1) * 100)))
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Basically, the `read()` function defined above reads in a file from line `start` to line `end`. Split the reading tasks into 5 segments so that 5 threads can simultaneously read the file.

---

## UPDATE UPON REQUEST

For your code, the

```
for config in configurations:
    try:
        "Do something with the url loaded fron file.csv"
            
    except Exception  as e: 
        print(e)
        failedConfigs.append(config)
```

Can be converted to a function which allows you to specify from which index to which index of the `configurations` you want to process:

```
def process(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        config = configurations[i]
        try:
            "Do something with the url loaded fron file.csv"

        except Exception  as e: 
            print(e)
            failedConfigs.append(config)
```

Which you can then add

```
threads = []
for i in range(5):
    threads.append(Thread(target=process, args=(i * 100, (i + 1) * 100)))
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

So you might end up with something like:

```
configurationsFile = "file.csv"
configurations = []


def loadConfigurations():
    with open(configurationsFile) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        line_count = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            url = row[0]
            line_count += 1
            configurations.append({"url": url})
        print(f'{line_count} urls loaded.')

loadConfigurations()

failedConfigs = []

session_requests = requests.session()

def process(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        config = configurations[i]
        try:
            "Do something with the url loaded fron file.csv"

        except Exception  as e: 
            print(e)
            failedConfigs.append(config)

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    threads.append(Thread(target=process, args=(i * 100, (i + 1) * 100)))
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()

if len(failedConfigs) > 0:
    print("These errored out:")
    for theConfig in failedConfigs:
        print("ERROR: {}".format(theConfig['url']))
```

Comment: Thanks, Im sure this is the way todo it. I just dont see how I can implement it into my code. Where do I put in the code that does something with the url it reads from the file? I allso prefer to use csv files since it could contain other fields then just urls.

Comment: One follow up question. If I change this: args=(i * 100, (i + 1) * 100))) to be 25 insted of 100, and file contains 250 urls, will it queue up each thread with 50 urls or will it just do the first 125 urls?

Comment: @andhaa The latter.